# Is it ever possible to define the square root of a negative number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, complex-numbers

I am making a thing that's just like the built-in Math in JavaScript, but it has other features like factorial, gamma function, summation, etc. I'm planning on doing imaginary numbers, like square root of negative 1.
When I saw that `-1^0.5` (square root when raising a number to the half power) is equal to `NaN`. A lot of things are equal to NaN though, like 1-"a", or 1÷0, etc. Here is (a portion of) my code:

```
/*What I'm Thinking*/
foo {
    ...
    pow: function(x, y){ // maybe?
        ...
    }
    I: "i", // Probably not the efficient way
    I2: -1 // ...
    // and more crazy ideas
}
```

I was even thinking of doing a function to do it. My last idea was another pow function, and when the base is negative, it won't give up and maybe return "i" or something; but once again, strings are probably not the most efficient way because of addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, etc. which is the hard part.
**Is there any other better method to making imaginary numbers, or at least any that would help, or is this technically impossible in JavaScript?**

Comment: You could define a `Complex` type. See http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/complex_numbers.html, for example.

Comment: You would then also have to do `(-1)^0.25 = (1+i)/sqrt(2)`, so indeed a complex data type is required. What would you think the result of `(-1)^0.26` or `(-1)^0.25001` should be, and why?

Comment: @Ryan, thank you for your suggestion! :D I'm surprised how many features it has :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to consider two modes that both have advantages and disadvantages that have a balance that depends on the actual situation.

In the **real numbers** mode, the `pow` function has, if at all (i.e., the basis is non-negative), a unique result that obeys the usual power laws like `a^(b+c)=a^b*a^c`, `(a*b)^c=a^c*b^c` and `a^(b*c) = (a^b)^c`.

In the **complex numbers** mode, the `pow` function has almost always **a** result. However, the defining relations/ equations will then also almost always have multiple solutions that could equally well be the values of this function. For rational exponents one may think of set-valued results, the roots of a polynomial equation. For irrational or even complex exponents the results exist just by continuity without intrinsic meaning.

The usual way to allow for both modes is to have a complex data type such that only on arguments of this data type the complex version of `pow` is used. As operator overloading does not exist in javascript, you can not have a complex data type where `c=a*b` is syntactically correct, you have to use syntax like `c=a.mul(b)` or `c=Complex.mul(a,b)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass an object that resolves itself to values when used in math operations:

```
var I={
 toString:_=>"I",
 valueOf:_=>NaN,
 pow:_=>I
}
```

usecases:

```
console.log(I*2);//NaN
console.log(I+" is a string now");
console.log(I.pow(5));
```

Implemented in Math.pow:

```
var temp=Math.pow
Math.pow=function(a,b){
  return temp(a,b) || I;
}

Number.prototype.pow=function(a){ return Math.pow(this,a);};

console.log(
 Math.pow(5,2),
 Math.pow(-1,0.5),//I
 Math.pow(5,2).pow(2),
 Math.pow(-1,0.5).pow(5)//I
);
```

Comment: That's not what I mean. I meant the variable I being treated as the square root of -1, which is a complex number. In JavaScript, it treats the square root of negative one as Not a Number, which I do NOT want. I just want something like: `Math.pow(foo.i, 2) = -1`, or `Math.pow(-1, 0.5)=foo.i`.

Comment: @Christian *Is there any other better method to making imaginary numbers, or at least any that would help, or is this technically impossible in JavaScript?* <- the question ive answered. you can override Math.pow for shure